# How integrate a react-redux app into another react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react-redux app and I would like to display the content of another react app ( from another team) when a user clicks on a button.

so far I had found articles about sharing components between react apps or using npm package. like this [building a react component library](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-react-component-library-part-1-d8a1e248fe6c)

but I haven't found an example to package a whole app (including reducers/actions) and imported as dependency into another app

I see also there is micro frontends but not sure how to use that with react apps.

any suggestions or examples would be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance